# ENC28J60 Stops receiving

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, tcp, lwip

I'm currently using an stm32f405 and an ENC28J60 and lwip as tcp/ip stack. Everything runs fine at startup but after about a minute or so the ENC stops receiving packets. Transmitting keeps working fine. I've tried both polling it and using interrupts.

I'm using https://github.com/wolfgangr/enc28j60 to communicate to the ENC. And this is the code that handles incoming packets:

```
while (true) {

eventmask_t mask = chEvtWaitAnyTimeout(ALL_EVENTS, LWIP_PACKET_POLL_INTERVAL);

if(mask & ENC_INTERRUPT_ID)
{
  /* Handle ENC28J60 interrupt */
  ENC_IRQHandler(&encHandle);
  /* Reenable interrupts */
  ENC_EnableInterrupts(EIE_INTIE);
}

if (mask & PERIODIC_LINK_TIMER_ID)
{
  bool current_link_status = ((encHandle.LinkStatus) & PHSTAT2_LSTAT) != 0;

  if (current_link_status != prev_link_status) {
    if (current_link_status) {
      dhcp_start(&thisif);
    }
    else {
      dhcp_stop(&thisif);
    }
  }
  prev_link_status = current_link_status;
}

/* Check if new frames where received */
struct pbuf *p;

while ((p = low_level_input(&thisif)) != NULL) {

  struct eth_hdr *ethhdr = p->payload;
  switch (htons(ethhdr->type)) {
  /* IP or ARP packet? */
  case ETHTYPE_IP:
  case ETHTYPE_ARP:

    /* full packet send to tcpip_thread to process */
    if (tcpip_input(p, &thisif) == ERR_OK)
      break;
    LWIP_DEBUGF(NETIF_DEBUG, ("ethernetif_input: IP input error\n"));
  default:
    pbuf_free(p);
  }
}
}
```

Function low_level_input:

```
static struct pbuf *low_level_input(struct netif *netif) {
struct pbuf *p = NULL;
struct pbuf *q;
uint16_t len;
uint8_t *buffer;
uint32_t bufferoffset = 0;

if (!ENC_GetReceivedFrame(&encHandle)) {
  return NULL;
}

/* Obtain the size of the packet and put it into the "len" variable. */
len = encHandle.RxFrameInfos.length;
buffer = (uint8_t *)encHandle.RxFrameInfos.buffer;

if (len > 0)
{
  /* We allocate a pbuf chain of pbufs from the Lwip buffer pool */
  p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_RAW, len, PBUF_POOL);
}

if (p != NULL)
{
  bufferoffset = 0;

  for(q = p; q != NULL; q = q->next)
  {
    /* Copy data in pbuf */
    memcpy( (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)q->payload), (uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)buffer + bufferoffset), q->len);
    bufferoffset = bufferoffset + q->len;
  }
}

return p;
}
```

After a while the function ENC_GetReceivedFrame keeps returning false, even if I know for sure some packets should have been received.
I've debugged the function (found in enc28j60.c) and this line:

```
pktcnt = enc_rdbreg(handle, ENC_EPKTCNT);
```

pktcnt is always 0. I've looked at the SPI bus with a logic analyzer and the ENC truly anwsers 0. The SPI bus works fine.

Just before this happens some packets are received that are not flagged as RXSTAT_OK (look at line 1259 in enc28j60.c)

I've been at this for day's now, and truly have no ideas left.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem..
The EPKTCNT register was times to times decreased with no reason( without setting the ECON2_PKTDEC bit).
I noticed that when it happened it was after setting the ECON2_AUTOINC bit.
Not every time ECON2_AUTOINC was set but often.

I just set ECON2_AUTOINC at the initialization of the ENC28J60, no more during the reading process.
Since EPKTCNT stopped to decrease with no reason.

Hope it can help